# Passing params object[] changes URL generated by Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the `Url.Action` method in many of my API methods to specify route to the current object and related objects. The code looks like this:

```
public class FooController : BaseController
{
    protected override string ControllerName => "FooController";

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetSingle(int id)
    {
        var entity = base.DbContext.FooEntities.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);

        var selfUrl = Url.Action(
            action: nameof(GetSingle),
            controller: this.ControllerName,
            protocol: Request.Scheme,
            values: new { id }
        );

        var viewModel = mapper.Map<FooViewModel>(entity, selfUrl);

        return Ok(viewModel);
    }
}
```

This code produces the URL as expected.

```
http://localhost:1080/foo/1
```

Since the Request.Scheme property is always the same and the ControllerName is an abstract property in the BaseController, I tried to extract the URL-building method into the BaseController like this:

```
protected string GetActionUrl(string actionName, params object[] values)
{
    return Url.Action(
        action: actionName,
        controller: this.ControllerName,
        protocol: Request.Scheme,
        values: values);
}
```

And called it from the FooController's GetSingle method like this:

```
var selfUrl = base.GetActionUrl(nameof(GetSingle), id);
```

However, this produced a totally different URL:

```
http://localhost:1080/foo?Length=1&LongLength=1&Rank=1&SyncRoot=1&SyncRoot=System.Object%5B%5D&IsReadOnly=False&IsFixedSize=True&IsSynchronized=False
```

I tried wrapping the id into a new object structure:

```
var selfUrl = base.GetActionUrl(nameof(GetSingle), id);
```

This did not help much:

```
http://localhost:1080/foo?Length=1&LongLength=1&Rank=1&SyncRoot=%7B%20id%20%3D%201%20%7D&IsReadOnly=False&IsFixedSize=True&IsSynchronized=False
```

What is causing this behavior? And how should I implement/code the GetActionUrl method so that I get the desired result?

Comment: It clearly doesn't recognize the values. Use `RouteValueDictionary` instead.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Please, could you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binder clearly doesn't recognize the values as parameters. You need some kind of method to map keys and values. You can use anonymous classes for this, but in your case it would be easier to use the `RouteValueDictionary` instead.

So instantiate an instance of that dictionary, fill it as you normally would, and pass that to this method.